# How load Emberjs 2.0 with jspm and systemjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jspm, systemjs

I am try use Ember 2.0 and have next files
config.js

```
System.config({
  "baseURL": "/static/js",
  "transpiler": "traceur",
  "paths": {
    "*": "*.js",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*.js"
  }
});

System.config({
  "map": {
    "ember": "github:components/ember@2.0.0",
    "traceur": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.88",
    "traceur-runtime": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.88",
    "github:components/ember@2.0.0": {
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4",
      "handlebars": "github:components/handlebars@1.3.0"
    }
  }
});
```

app.js

```
import Ember from "ember";
let App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
});
```

and index.html

```
<script src="{% static "js/jspm_packages/system.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/config.js" %}"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app');
</script>
```

aftre load i have next error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot read property 'Ember' of undefined
    Error loading http://localhost:9090/static/js/app.js
    at http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/github/components/ember@2.0.0/ember.js!transpiled:16:38
    at http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/github/components/ember@2.0.0/ember.js!transpiled:97:11
    at execute (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/github/components/ember@2.0.0/ember.js!transpiled:25603:9)
    at m (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/system.js:4:20821)
    at m (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/system.js:4:20756)
    at m (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/system.js:4:20756)
    at Object.Promise.all.then.execute (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/system.js:4:23421)
    at b (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/system.js:4:7874)
    at S (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/system.js:4:8253)
    at p (http://localhost:9090/static/js/jspm_packages/system.js:4:6131)
```

if load scripts without systemjs and jspm always work. but want use jspm and systemjs :)
Before i use ember 1.13 and with config worked. I think problem with config jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the package for Ember is not always jspm-compatible. I always use the following override in my `package.json`:

```
"jspm": {
  "overrides": {
      "github:components/ember@2.0.0": {
      "main": "ember.debug",
      "files": [
        "ember.prod.js",
        "ember.debug.js"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "github:components/jquery@^2.1.3"
      },
      "shim": {
        "ember.prod": {
          "deps": [
            "jquery"
          ],
          "exports": "Ember"
        },
        "ember.debug": {
          "deps": [
            "jquery"
          ],
          "exports": "Ember"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It dictates jspm to install only prod and debug versions of Ember and describes all dependencies and exports properly. If you use it, you need to run `jspm install` again after you added it to your package.json.

You may encounter another problem with htmlbars templates. I have got a plugin to solve that: https://github.com/n-fuse/plugin-ember-hbs:

`jspm install hbs=github:n-fuse/plugin-ember-hbs@2.0.0`

should allow importing hbs templates w/o the need to add a compiler in dependencies.

See also a starter project I created: https://github.com/OrKoN/jspm-ember-playground